# Why is my asp.net core cshtml view not rendering?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I press the delete button in my DataTable it should bring me to the DeleteUserConfirm view. I can see that the data needed to display the page is being passed. However, the page is not displaying and I do not receive any errors. Any thoughts or suggestions to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

The code for the DataTable is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--CSS for DataTables-->
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>All Accounts</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        <table id="allAccounts" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Organization</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to Home</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#allAccounts').DataTable(
                {
                    "responsive": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/api/User/GetUsers",
                        "dataSrc": ""

                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "FirstName" },
                        { "data": "LastName" },
                        { "data": "Organization" },
                        { "data": "State" },
                        {
                            "data": "Id",
                            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return "<button class='btn btn-danger' style=margin-right:5px; onclick=DeleteUser(" + row.Id + ")>Delete</button>"

                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
        });

        function DeleteUser(data) {
            $.ajax({
                "type": "POST",
                "url": "/api/User/Delete/",
                "data": JSON.stringify(data),
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

Once the delete button is clicked, the data is sent to the Delete method in the User Controller, which is an API Controller. The code for the Delete method is below:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Delete([FromBody] int data)
    {
       

        return RedirectToAction("DeleteUserConfirm", "Home", new { id = data });
    }
```

The Delete method in the User Controller redirects to the Home Controller where the data is passed and the DeleteUserConfirm view should be displayed. The DeleteUserConfirm method from the Home Controller is below:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult DeleteUserConfirm(int id)
        {              
            return View(_userRepository.GetUser(id));
        }
```

The code for the DeleteUserConfirm view is below:

```
@model Project.Models.User

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Confirm Rejection/Deletion";
}

<h1>Confirm Account Rejection/Deletion</h1>
<br/>
<br/>
<h4>Are you sure you want to reject and delete this account?</h4>
<div>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </dd>
    </dl>

    <form asp-action="DeleteUser">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.Id" />
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formnovalidate />
    </form>
    <br/>
    <a asp-action="Accounts">Back to Account Management</a>
</div>
```

I make it all the way to the DeleteUserConfirm method in the Home Controller. I can see that the user is being retrieved from the GetUser(Id) method. I just do not get taken to the view itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to RedirectToAction in the controller because your request is coming from client side via ajax.

Instead, just redirect directly to your DeleteUserConfirm when the user clicks the button.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#allAccounts').DataTable(
                {
                    "responsive": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/api/User/GetUsers",
                        "dataSrc": ""

                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "FirstName" },
                        { "data": "LastName" },
                        { "data": "Organization" },
                        { "data": "State" },
                        {
                            "data": "Id",
                            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return "<a class='btn btn-danger' style='margin-right:5px;' href='/Home/DeleteUserConfirm/" + row.Id + "'>Delete</a>"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
        });

}
```

Comment: I tried this and the view is still not rendering. However, it did make my DataTable load quicker, so thank you for that!

Comment: There was a small mistake in my answer. I updated the render function to return: "<a class='btn btn-danger' style=margin-right:5px; href='/Home/DeleteUserConfirm/" + row.Id + "'>Delete</a>" so that the last single quote in the href comes after the double quote. Please give that a try. If the view still does not render, try navigating directly to /Home/DeleteUserConfirm/[Some Valid UserID] in the browser url bar.

Comment: I fixed the quotes and it still does not render. I went directly to the page via the browser and it did render, showing the information of the Id I put.

Comment: Just noticed the style attribute has no quotes around margin-right:5px in the render method (updated my answer). Please try adding quotes around margin-right:5px because that may be interfering with the href attribute. Also check the rendered html in the developer tools if the page still does not render after clicking the delete button. You are very close.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it this way using `ajax`. Returning a view is possible, but you need to update it manually via javascript. Currently your ajax is not doing anything after successful request. Update your ajax to this:

```
$.ajax({
   "type": "POST",
   "url": "/api/User/Delete/",
   "data": JSON.stringify(data),
   "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).done(function(html){
    $('#Container').html(html);
}).fail(function(){
   console.error('error');
});
```

and ideally, you should return `PartialView` from controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DeleteUserConfirm(int id)
{              
    return PartialView(_userRepository.GetUser(id));
}
```

You may have to call `home/DeleteUserConfirm/` directly in ajax, but you can try with API to see if its working.

or if you just need to redirect to another page, do it in `done` callback.

```
$.ajax({
   "type": "POST",
   "url": "/api/User/Delete/",
   "data": JSON.stringify(data),
   "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).done(function(){
    window.location.href = 'url';
}).fail(function(){
   console.error('error');
});
```